# Given $n$, how to construct $n$ points

Tags: geometry

Given $n$, how to construct $n$ points on a plane s.t. any 3 points are not on a line, and the distance between any 2 points is an integer?

Below is how to do it for $n=6$ here ABC is the 3,4,5 triangle.
[image: n=6]

Comment: looks like $x_k=(2^k,3^k)$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ is doing the job

Comment: The link shows there is no limit if you allow all the points to be on a circle.

Comment: @Surb:  the distance between $(2,3)$ and $(4,9)$ is $\sqrt {40}$, not an integer.

Comment: @RossMillikan ah... indeed, I misread the question.